# NaCL sealed box on different platforms

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption, public-key-encryption

There is `tweetnacl-sealedbox-js` for node.js

For example we can encrypt some data

```
const key = crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(32);
const publicKey = 'ed9f2af89336b2ff5960634fafb401ca36644cad61cb6a1daafdda0c74ef4636';
const encryptedKey = seal(key, Buffer.from(publicKey, 'hex'));
```

But is there similar library for C# ? I'm trying to use libsodium-net but am not completely sure that this is correct

For example

```
byte[] randKey = new byte[32];
Random.NextBytes(randKey);
string publicKey = "ed9f2af89336b2ff5960634fafb401ca36644cad61cb6a1daafdda0c74ef4636";
byte[] encryptedKey = SealedPublicKeyBox.Create(randKey, HexToByte(publicKey));
public static byte [] HexToByte(string hexStr)
        {
            byte[] bArray = new byte[hexStr.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < (hexStr.Length / 2); i++)
            {
                byte firstNibble = Byte.Parse(hexStr.Substring((2 * i), 1), 
                                   System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); // [x,y)
                byte secondNibble = Byte.Parse(hexStr.Substring((2 * i) + 1, 1), 
                                    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                int finalByte = (secondNibble) | (firstNibble << 4);
                bArray[i] = (byte)finalByte;
            }
            return bArray;
        }
```

Does anybody know can the owner of private key decrypt both messages? or c# code is not the same action?

Answer (score 0):

SO I make some tests: 
run `var keyPair = tweetnacl.box.keyPair()` at node.js and convert to base64 strings public key and secret key.

```
var pubKey = Buffer.from('Uv4bICdcUlIO+Z9YsLLg9EGaLPy/M7oTBVZJn2B7XhU=', 'base64');
var secKey = Buffer.from('fEAUUQ+axuD3NkOr+a59ZtsVurZPTa4Ee8ULoNr3WS0=', 'base64');
```

try to encrypt message via c# and `libsodium-net` like that:

```
string mes = "i want to believe";
string pKey = "Uv4bICdcUlIO+Z9YsLLg9EGaLPy/M7oTBVZJn2B7XhU=";

byte [] enc = Sodium.SealedPublicKeyBox.Create(mes, Convert.FromBase64String(pKey));

return Convert.ToBase64String(enc);
```

and try to decrypt message via node.js

```
var msg = Buffer.from('uW+5ecQhzKKx++uRYcbCu2nUVNIqToWTSjVB7UmdDCeJn9Buf3UWFu5kRfIGIxMJYdVeTFijdvJhlHR0VBd5HnE=', 'base64');
var result = sealedbox.open(msg, pubKey, secKey);
console.log(Buffer.from(result).toString());
```

and got my message in log.

so I found out that these libraries are mutually compatible.